How to set the start_time and end_time Asset property programatically?
I have a schedule pipeline that updates on daily basis an ee.ImageCollection asset. Each new image is fully defined with start and end time. At first I thought that the start and end time from the Image Collection were computed from the embeded image but they are static information.
So I would like to change ths value at the end of my script like:
ee.data.setAssetProperties(
  "projects/ecmwf-hres-forecast-rasters/assets/meteomatics_mix", 
  {"start_date": "1998-06-03"}
)

If I do so I'm not modifying the system parameter and I don't know which format I should use for the value (timestamp, string, datetime)?
Is it possible and if yes can someone give a simple example ?

They're set the same way you'd set them for images.
ee.data.setAssetProperties(path, {
   "system:time_end": 1609259200000,
   "system:time_start": 1577136800000
}

The time is milliseconds since unix epoch.

I opened an issue in the Google issue tracker but it seems that you cannot modify these values from the API if they are not already existing.
